# PHP - getting real time data from the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I've been trying to get data from my database by php and PDO. Before I ask the question, I want to show you the part of the database that i want to get in real-time:

[image: Database]

the data I want to get is: CPU_util in real time.

** CPU_util moves between 0 to 100

In the website I'm using the plugin: highcharts in order to display the CPU_util. The chart the I picked up is this ([link to the chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update)):

[image: Spline updating each second]

### My question is:

How to get the data in CPU_util from the database and put it in the chart in real time?

(X axis should be as it is (the current time) and the Y axis moves between 0 to 100)

### What I've been trying so far:

I did some coding with ajax, but after some tries the website blocks me, because I passed the number limit of http request (2000 requests).

Comment: Your question and title are two different things.

Comment: Websockets is better suited to achieving long polling/real time data.

Comment: It's a bad idea to request data from a database or other persistant data storages if you want that data realtime. If you really want this, your best chance is to set up a stream (long get requests) to some server. The server then should listen to the source that outputs the data for CPU_Util.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale Edited

Comment: @MackieeE Thanks, I'll try

Comment: @Glubus do you have good tutorials for this?

Comment: I have never implemented something like this, but WebSockets and the long get requests (it has a name, but I cant be bothered to look for it) are widely used nowadays, so you shouldn't have too much trouble finding a way to do this. About the CPU, you need to have direct access to the source outputting the CPU_util data, so instead of sending it to the mysql table, you need to direct it to the stream that you need to setup.

Comment: I ***think*** i can come up with a way @iYonatan . Ima anwser now.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale Ok thanks!!

Comment: @Glubus Thanks for the help. I'll try to do what you said

Comment: @iYonatan i made an anwser. But if you want these types of things you should get more used to WebSockets. And a good langauge to learn will be [Go](https://golang.org) !

Comment: @Glubus I think you are referring to `long polling`, however websockets are by far superior.

Comment: Eh as far as I know long polling works only for one transaction each time. I.e. client sends request, waits for answer, repeat. What Im referring to is a get request that remains open for a longer period of time, allowing a server to keep sending data through it. Last time I checked this is how Google implemented it's Google Drive's Word clone when multi-editing (you can test it by editting it with 2 different sessions, check the console).

Answer (score 3):

Realtime PHP is a completely different animal compared to 'normal' web apps.
As already suggested, websockets or http-long-polling is the way to go.

The big issue to tackle is dealing with the HTTP request limit and not crashing your server and not starting a php(-fom) thread for each request you are making. To achieve this you will have to rethink your architecture a bit.

To achieve realtime php you'd want non-blocking evented php on the server (nodejs style). In the world of php the most used library for achieving this is Ratchet.

If you want to learn more:

- http://socketo.me/docs/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-quickly-build-a-chat-app-with-ratchet/

Also, if you're really doing ALOT of calls to mysql, you may want to move this data to a separate high performance db like `Redis`